# Authentication state prop not set before page rendering

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, react-redux, react-router-dom

I am using redux in my simple react project and I am setting protected route which is supposed to fire a redirect in case the user is not logged in.

My **initial state** looks like this:

```js
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  email: '',
  password: '',
  error: '',
  loading: false,
  loggedIn: false
};
```

the render function in my component looks like this:

```js
if (!loggedIn) {
  return (<Spinner />);
}  

if (loggedIn === false) {

  return (
    <Redirect to={{
      pathname: '/login',
      state: { from: this.props.location }
    }} />
  )
}
return (
  <Route {...this.props} />
)
```

Now, when a user is logged in, everything works fine, the spinner is displayed until the content is loaded.

The problem arises when a user is not logged in, then the spinner is displayed and nothing else happens, the redirect basically is not called. I can see in the console that the state is set only when I run the component, and not updated at all later on, as I am not calling any function. I am wondering if I should set an extra function in the componentWillMount() part, or something like that? Or am I just messing around with undefined and false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two statements which check the same thing `!loggedIn`, it gets to the first statement resulting in `spinner` because of `return` it does not go further.

Assuming `loading` works fine, you can try this -

```js
if (!loggedIn) {
  return (
    <Redirect to={{
      pathname: '/login',
      state: { from: this.props.location }
    }} />
  )
}

if (loading) {
  return (<Spinner />);
}

return (
  <Route {...this.props} />
)
```

Comment: thanks @grgmo. Actually I am not using the loading at all now, as I am not fetching any data. I am wondering if there's a way to block the rendering until all the props are finished loading? In that case I could display the spinner while te props are loading.